# How to choose a specific instance of a custom class added to Interface Builder, or suggest a better organization

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm writing a single-window, non-document-based app for Mac OSX. I'm coming from an iOS project where we avoided Interface Builder like the plague. I'm forcing myself to use it for the Mac project just for the experience.

My program's menu and its main window are in two different nibs. The window contains a toolbar. Of course many of the toolbar and menu items are representing the same function, so I want to route them through the same code. Initially I put all the handlers for the menu/toolbar in my application controller and wired them to the menu/toolbar using Interface Builder. Then I realized many of the operations affect the window and its contents, not the entire program, so I thought it more appropriate to put those methods in the main window controller.

To support this I added an NSObject to my window nib, changed its class to my window controller class, and wired those up.

Of course what I'm seeing now is that my app controller creates an instance of the window controller when it creates my one-and-only window, AND the nib for the menu creates another instance of the window controller when it builds the interface from the nib. That may or may not prove to be problematic, but it seems wasteful. Seems like everybody should be talking to the one-and-only window controller I create in applicationDidFinishLaunching.

So question 1 is "How do I tell my program to use the existing window controller when building the user interface from the nib?"

If the answer to question 1 is "You don't" then I'm looking for a suggested organizational pattern to follow. Do I put all the menu/toolbar handlers in the app controller and route from there? Or is there some other common way of doing this that is consistent with the zeitgeist of Cocoa?